# Randomize letter color in javascript

Tags: javascript, random, colors, letter

I am trying to create a script that gives each individual letter inside "p" tags on my website a random color. The coloring part works fine, the problem is that my script overwrites "br" and "a" tags. Is there any workaround for this?

Here is my code so far:

```js
function changeColor() {
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
   
    for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
    {
        var innerText = paragraphs[i].innerText;
        var innerTextSplit = innerText.split("");
        paragraphs[i].innerText = ""
       
        for(var j = 0; j < innerTextSplit.length; j++) {
            var randomColor = "rgb(" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) + ");"
 
            innerTextSplit[j] = '<span style="color: ' + randomColor + '">' + innerTextSplit[j] + '</span>';
            paragraphs[i].innerHTML += innerTextSplit[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

-jAndersen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegant, but try:

```
function changeColor() {
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
{
    var innerText = paragraphs[i].innerHTML;
    var innerTextSplit = innerText.split("");
    paragraphs[i].innerText = "";

    var isHTMLElement = false;

    for(var j = 0; j < innerTextSplit.length; j++) {
        if(innerTextSplit[j] == "<")
          isHTMLElement = true;

        if(!isHTMLElement){
          var randomColor = "rgb(" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) + ", " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 255) + 1) + ");"
          innerTextSplit[j] = '<span style="color: ' + randomColor + '">' + innerTextSplit[j] + '</span>';
        }

        if(innerTextSplit[j] == ">")
            isHTMLElement = false;

    }

    innerTextSplit = innerTextSplit.join('');
    paragraphs[i].innerHTML += innerTextSplit;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!, not only does it work, it also solves a browser crash where the script would try to parse the span tags as well, when you press the button a second time. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Please find below snippet there is one function `getRandomColor()` for generating random color hexa code

```js
$(function(){
changeColor();
});

function changeColor() {
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
   
    for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
    {
        var innerText = paragraphs[i].innerText;
        var innerTextSplit = innerText.split("");
        paragraphs[i].innerText = ""
       
        for(var j = 0; j < innerTextSplit.length; j++) {
            var randomColor =getRandomColor();
 
            innerTextSplit[j] = '<span style="color: ' + randomColor + '">' + innerTextSplit[j] + '</span>';
            paragraphs[i].innerHTML += innerTextSplit[j];
        }
    }
}

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>geloosmsd</p>
<p>geloosmsd</p>
<p>geloosmsd</p><p>geloosmsd</p><p>geloosmsd</p><p>geloosmsd</p><p>geloosmsd</p><p>geloosmsd</p><p>geloosmsd</p><p>geloosmsd</p><p>geloosmsd</p><p>geloosmsd</p>
```

Comment: Oooh, thats a brilliant solution for making hex-codes, i hadnt even thought about doing it like that.

However, it doesnt fix the issue of recoloring breakline tags within the p-tags, if such are present. One question though, why are you using jquery to start the function?, that shouldnt be neccesary